# Displaying tables with ng-repeat containing ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi have this table displayed with angular JS .

```
 <div class="table-responsive ">    
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Pr&eacutenom</th>
                        <th>login</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>group</th>
                    </tr>           
                   </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in allusers ">
                        <td>{{ user.lastname}}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.firstname}}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.login}}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-group"
                            ng-click="getAllGroupsofUser(user.id)">
          <option ng-repeat="group in groupsofuser">{{group.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                         </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>        
    </table> 
    </div>
```

I'm consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS . when I click on the select  ( in a specific user row in  the the column group ) I get the correct list but  the problem is that all the column group will  change and will have the same select options.

how can I fix that ?

Comment: What does your user object look like? should that be `group in user.groupsofuser`?

Comment: That's fine...what does the array you're iterating over look like? Can you post a sample of the data received from the service?

Comment: The problem is that all row of `user` shares the same $scope.groupsofuser.

Comment: the problem is not in the data , I got the correct list of groups for each user but in the view each time I click the select it will change all the column (it will show the correct list but repeat it in all rows) because of the first ng-repeat

Comment: @yazaki yes this it , but what can I do to fix that ?

Comment: You're storing the groups of *one* specific user in a variable of the scope (`groupsofuser`), common to *all* the users. Don't do that. Instead, do as @tymeJV says: store the groups of the user *x* in an attribute of the user *x*.

Comment: Ok. I am going to describe my image of code which could solve your problem as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all row of `user` shares the same `$scope.groupsofuser`.
`user` need to have their own `groupsofuser` separately.

The code below (**without test**) might achieve what you want.

This is html.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in allusers">
            <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
            <td>
                <select ng-click="getAllGroupsofUser(user)">
                    <option ng-repeat="group in user.groupsofuser">{{group.name}}</option>
                </select>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

This is controller code.

```
$scope.getAllGroupsofUser = function(user){
    user.groupsofuser = someservice_use_rest(user.id);
};
```

I hope this could help you. Good luck!!

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question . this way I don't get  the list until I click on select . is there another way to fill it automatically

Comment: I would recommend to fill it at the same time when loading $scope.allusers.